# SetState using a filter is removing everything from the array

Tags: reactjs

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getXPosition, getYPosition } from 'helpers/location-helper';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { AircraftWrapper } from './aircraft.styles';

const Aircraft = ({ flightData, setFlight, flights }) => {
    const flightId = flightData.flightId;
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(flightData.coordinate);
    const [currentState, setState] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(currentState === false) {
            setFlight(flights.filter(item => item.flightId !== flightData?.flightId));
        }
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setLocation({...location, x: (location.x+(10*Math.cos(Math.PI/180*flightData?.heading))), y: location.y+(10*Math.sin(Math.PI/180*flightData?.heading))});
            if (location.x < -5 || location.y < 0 || location.x > 105 || location.y > 150) {
                setState(false);
            }
          }, 1000);
          return() => clearInterval(interval);
        }, [location, flightData.heading]);
        return(
        <AircraftWrapper 
        data-testid="aircraft"
        style={{left: `${getXPosition(location?.x)}`, top: `${getYPosition(location?.y)}`}}
        heading={flightData?.heading+85}
        />
    )
}

export default Aircraft;


//(150) + Math.cos(flightData.heading)*location.y
```

The error is in the if(currentState === false). It causes all aircrafts to be removed from the screen. What I am trying to do is based off of a timer, update the position of the aircraft and use a transition to move it forward until it goes past the map boundaries. as soon as it hits the map boundaries, it will disappear from the screen.

Comment: Show more code if possible, like what is ```console.log(flightData)```

Comment: flightData is {flightId: 'AA5479', planeType: 'A330', climbRate: 42, maxAltitude: 43000, altitude: 1995, …}
altitude: 1995
climbRate: 42
coordinate: {y: 0, x: 49}
destination: "SMALL"
flightId: "AA5479"
flightStatus: "arriving"
heading: 73
maxAltitude: 43000
maxSpeed: 580
minSpeed: 160
planeType: "A330"
runway: "7R"
speed: 440
}

Which is randomly generated on the spawn of an Aircraft component

Comment: The array of flights will show up like this 
0: {flightId: 'AA5479', planeType: 'A330', climbRate: 42, maxAltitude: 43000, altitude: 1995, …}
1: {flightId: 'NW9771', planeType: '747', climbRate: 42, maxAltitude: 43000, altitude: 4248, …}

Comment: and can u edit this line  const flightId = flightData.flightId; like  const flightId = flightData?.flightId;

Comment: i hope you put all the code, or the parent component for this component

Comment: @HibaYoussef that code is in the main file, where I generate new planes every 10 second interval and add them in. The adding them in works perfect but removing individual planes that reach the end location does not. `const Simulator = () => {
  const [scaleEnabled, setScaleEnabled] = useState (false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [flights, setFlight] = useState([]);`then I pass it down with
`<Map scaleEnabled={scaleEnabled} flights={flights} setFlight={setFlight} />`

Comment: In map I have `const Map = ({scaleEnabled, flights, setFlight}) => {
    return(
        <MapWrapper className="map" data-testid="map">
            {Locations.map((data) => {
            return (
                <Beacon data={data} />
            )}
            )}
            {flights.map((flight) => {
            return (
               <Aircraft flightData={flight} setFlight={setFlight} flights={flights}/>
            )}
            )}
          <Scale scaleEnabled={scaleEnabled}/>
        </MapWrapper>
    )
}` as a result of the function in Aircraft, it remove all aircrafts

Comment: can u edit this line const Map = ({scaleEnabled, flights, setFlight}) to const Map = (scaleEnabled, flights, setFlight)

Comment: yeah that breaks it. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') @HibaYoussef `{flights.map((flight) => {
            return (
               <Aircraft flightData={flight} setFlight={setFlight} flights={flights}/>
            )}
            )}`